# 3D touch shortcut application:didfinishlaunchingwithoptions: performActionForShortcutItem: Execution order

Tags: ios, 3dtouch, uiapplicationshortcutitem

If your app hasn't launched, and you click home shortcut item to launch your app, which method would be called first?

```
Is application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
```

or

```
application:performActionForShorcutItem:completionHandler:
```

?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you launch your app with 3D-touch shortcut ,the method:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
```

will be called first.
If this method return true ,the method :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, performActionForShortcutItem shortcutItem: UIApplicationShortcutItem, completionHandler: Bool -> Void)
```

will be called next.
But if you return false with the first method ,the second method will not be called.

If your app is already launched,you use 3D-touch shortcut to enter your app,only the second method will called.

See more details in [Apple's Demo](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/ApplicationShortcuts/ApplicationShortcutsUsingUIApplicationShortcutItem.zip)

Comment: So, I don't need to consider whether the window has rootViewController when I first launch the app through home shortcut item. Cause it(rootViewController) has benn launched in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method. Is that right?